# Как посчитать площадь здания из OSM? OSMnx

Tags: python, поиск-библиотек, openstreetmap

Есть ли библиотеки или готовые решения по данной теме? От OSM получаю полигон здания. В инете нашёл только один способ расчёта, да и он с погрешностью.

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8C+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0)